# Mapbox GL user location GPS offset rnmapbox/maps

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl-js, android-gps, mapbox-android

We have an app that implements rnmapbox/maps for an android build.

I have a very strange case where:
Users position does not match their current GPS location.
When they go into Google maps, it gives the correct location.

However, in our app there is an offset to this location.  We don't see this for any other users.  Their location permissions are turned on (validated).

Any ideas what could cause this kind of offset in Mapbox-GL?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: I am not familiar with React Native, but in Android SDK you can request ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission from the user. Could it have something to do with the user denying the fine location permission for your app specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we have not isolated the cause of this issue, it turns out that clearing the app data and installing an updated version seems to have resolved the issue.

It seems strange that when we investigated the app permissions they were apparently allowed, but it seems like this may have been the issue.

This may just be an issue of user experience.  If we find anything new I will post it.

Comment: I faced this issue with iOS and solved when I set `followUserLocation` with `true`.
In my environment I'm trying to use Mapbox with `@rnmapbox/maps` librrary in a expo react native project.